# How to loop string input into string array and then output it?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that reads words from the user until they enter the word “quit”, at which point it prints out all the words they entered on one line separated by commas.

I previously got the last user input (quit) to be only outputted, but now I am lost. Help. There is some commented out code. Thanks. I am new to Java but know C/C++ and UE4.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    String[] array = new String[1000];

    for (int i=1; i>0; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter string: ");
        array[i] = scanner.nextLine();

        if (array.equals("quit")) {
            System.out.println(array);
            break;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: you need `array[i].equals("quit")` and loop is faulty

Comment: if you want the loop to run until the user enters `quit`, it's better to use a `while` loop rather than making an infinite for loop.

Comment: You might want to use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array))` instead.

Comment: Also, if you want an infinite for loop, it's un-necessary to increment `i` when it's not needed. Simply, omit the third part like so `for(int i = 1; i>0;) {...}`

Comment: @Aominè Just as a note, this loop isn't infinite. It ends when `i` overflows.

Answer (score 4):

1. I would advice to use collection `ArrayList` instead of regular array. So you don't need to worry about size.
2. Make an infinite loop
3. Constants always should be on the left side of comparison. In this particular case `line` is not nullable, but this is good practice at all.

Eventually the code will look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter string: ");
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if ("quit".equals(line)) {
            break;
        }
        buffer.add(line);
    }
    System.out.println(buffer);
}
```

Hope it helps!

P.S. This will not print "quit" at the end, if you want to get it printed move `buffer.add(line);` before `if` statement.

Comment: a do while loop might be slightly nicer. He also asked for the strings to be printed separated by commas, otherwise great answer

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
    String word=null;
    ArrayList<String> words= new ArrayList<String>();
    do{
        System.out.print("Type your word: ");
        word=keyboard.next();
        if(word.equalsIgnoreCase("Quit")) break;
        words.add(word);
    }while(true);


    System.out.println("You typed: ");
    for(String w: words){
        System.out.print(w+",");
    }

}

}
```

You dont know the number of loops so you need "while" not "for". 
if user type quit it stops. If not, you add this word into the ArrayList.
In the end, you traverse this ArrayList and print all the words with a comma.

Comment: This will add a comma to the end of the list. You might want to try the StringJoiner class of java8

Answer (score 0):

You forget to show an index of the array and also you need to change the withdrawing:

```
  if (array[i].equals("quit")) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array))
      break;
  }
```

Comment: You might want to use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use a class named `TextIO` which can be found [here](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs124/javanotes5/source/TextIO.java). This class has the methods that will make your problem easier. First of all, an introduction:

TextIO is a class that works on control pointer which is moved ahead immediately after TextIO reads some text. E.g. if the user enters the string:

```
Hello World
```

then the default pointer position will be start of the text. If you run the statement:

```
String str = TextIO.getWord();
```

`str` will contain the string `Hello` and now the pointer position will be right in front of `Hello`. Now again if you call some other methods, TextIO will return the output starting from the current pointer position.

---

Coming to your problem now, TextIO contains a method `peek()` which returns the character that is just ahead the pointer position *without changing the pointer position*. This is useful if you want to pre-determine the next character in your text(the desired character being a comma in your case).
This is how you would do the coding:

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
while(true){
    TextIO.skipWhiteSpace();//Skips any white space(blacks, carriage returns etc. ) that may be preceding your next word.
    String str = TextIO.getWord();
    if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
        break;}
    if(TextIO.peek() != ','){
        ...Show error message...
        break;
    }
    TextIO.getChar();//Skip the comma that is the next character
    array.add(str);
}
```

I hope that helps!